# Make json array from mysql query

Tags: php, json

I am trying the following code:

```
$order = array(); $imageURL = array(); $name = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql->result)) {
            $order[] = $row["order"]; 
            $imageURL[] = $row["imageURL"];
            $name[] = $row["name"];
        }
        $res = array($order, $imageURL,$name);
        return json_encode($res);
```

But it is not outputting in json format, any ideas?

Output:

```
[["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30"],["previews\/en-1-1.gif","previews\/en-1-2.gif","previews\/en-1-3.gif","previews\/en-1-4.gif","previews\/en-1-5.gif","previews\/en-1-6.gif","previews\/en-1-7.gif","previews\/en-1-8.gif","previews\/en-1-9.gif","previews\/en-1-10.gif","previews\/en-1-11.gif","previews\/en-1-12.gif","previews\/en-1-13.gif","previews\/en-1-14.gif","previews\/en-1-15.gif","previews\/en-1-16.gif","previews\/en-1-17.gif","previews\/en-1-18.gif","previews\/en-1-19.gif","previews\/en-1-20.gif","previews\/en-1-21.gif","previews\/en-1-22.gif","previews\/en-1-23.gif","previews\/en-1-24.gif","previews\/en-1-25.gif","previews\/en-1-26.gif","previews\/en-1-27.gif","previews\/en-1-28.gif","previews\/en-1-29.gif","previews\/en-1-30.gif"],["Helasd you?","Where sasaddsdam?","Weasdd!","Tasasdther","AtsaddsaBeach","Cheasd Hotel","At the Hotel","aaaaaaaaat?","At the Market","Aasdt's","Mesadasd th","Shdsdsssg","sssss","On aaaa","Do you work or study?","aaaaaaa","At tadstation","aaaaaae Gym","How doasdto\u2026?","Planning a Trip","At adsk","At the asdurant","At the Inads00e9","My Taaaog","A Meetiaaaaay adher","Tourist sdsadn Centre","Saaaaing","Aaaaaa Match","Lookaaasd","At tasda"]]
```

Comment: Why do you split up the result into 3 different arrays?

Comment: Are you returning from a function? If not, try outputting it instead using `echo` or `print`

Comment: @KodleeYin i read it somewhere

Comment: What are you getting? are you sure the query result is not empty, and why split the array? and change return for echo

Comment: You're also calling `mysql_fetch_array()` proceduarlly while using an object as your query resource... While this is not necessarily incorrect it's definitely weird and most likely isn't what you're meaning to do...

Comment: see the output in edited post above

Comment: It seems this can be answered here -- that is, if you are outputting to JavaScript.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373315/is-there-a-way-to-pass-multiple-arrays-to-php-json-encode-and-parse-it-with-jque

Comment: It is outputting json: An array of arrays. What do you want / expect, objects?

Comment: i want some kind of multi dimensial array so look up 1 and get the order etc. values

Comment: @Jake You have an array available in php in the `$res` variable. If you need to access the values in another language, you would need to parse the json first in that language. Note that json is a string, not an object or array.

Comment: @Jake - that output is as expected from your code. If you want an **object**, meaning you will have references like key value pairs in PHP associative arrays, why don't you add `$row` to an output array in each iteration *as a whole*, then encode that, i.e. the complete database output you're returning

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just after a better format to work with in your output, because you've currently set it up with three arrays and you'll have to reference each record's properties across these arrays by a numeric key.

[I've reconstructed an example](https://eval.in/167334) of what your original database output would look like:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);

$row = array();
list($orders, $imageURLS, $names) = $array;
foreach($orders as $key => $val) {
  $row[] = array(
    'order' => $val,
    'imageURL' => $imageURLS[$key],
    'name' => $names[$key]
  );
}
```

So in **your** code, you should try this:

```
$output = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql->result)) {
    $output[] = $row;
}
return json_encode($output);
```

[And you'll get a much easier data structure to work with.](https://eval.in/167335) Example:

```
[
  {
    "order": "1",
    "imageURL": "previews\/en-1-1.gif",
    "name": "Helasd you?"
  },
  {
    "order": "2",
    "imageURL": "previews\/en-1-2.gif",
    "name": "Where sasaddsdam?"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the comments to your original question, it looks like you're looking for :

```
 $main_array = array() ;    


    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql->result)) {

        $res = array($row["order"], $row["imageURL"],$row["name"]);   
        $main_array[] = $res; 
    }

    return json_encode($main_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

The output is correct. A json array, containing three json arrays. But I guess you want each element to be a separate array/object, containing `order`, `imageURL`, `name`. If that is correct, try something like:

```
$result = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql->result)) {
$result[] = array("order"=>$row["order"], "imageURL" => $row["imageURL"],"name"=> $row["name"])
}
$res = array($order, $imageURL, $name);
return json_encode($result);
```